# How to create "Code Behind" Blazor Components with VS 2019?

Tags: blazor

I can create an inline component like

```cs
<h1>@foo</h1>

@functions {

    string foo = "foo";
}
```

However when I create `Foo.razor` containing just:

```html
<h1>@foo</h1>
```

And `Foo.razor.cs` containing:

```cs
namespace MyApp.Client.Components {
    public class Foo: ComponentBase {

        public string foo;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Error   CS0101  The namespace 'MyApp.Client.Components' already contains a definition for 'Foo'
```

I am using the latest VS 2019 and Blazor libraries.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since October 2019, it is possible to use partial classes. So today you can name the class in the code-behind file like this:

```cs
public partial class Foo : ComponentBase
{
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

If you name the class file `Foo.razor.cs` it will appear under the `Foo.razor` razor file in solution explorer.

Comment: If your class is generic you will need to add `@typeparam T` to the .razor file.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE: This is now possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59470941/1141089

---

Currently (May 13, 2019), the "code-behind" and .razor view can't share the same name.

So when you have `Foo.razor.cs` and `Foo.razor` it is seen as the same file and thus causes a collision.

Workaround for now:
Rename your `Foo.razor.cs` to `FooBase.cs` (or something else).

Then in your `Foo.razor`, add `@inherits FooBase`

There is a GitHub issue regarding this here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5487

Comment: This answer is out of date. Check out @Knelis' answer

Answer (score 8):

I don't like explaining ways by words but visualizing.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Vs2019 v 16.8.4 using the experimintal Razor, a new option "Extract block to code behind"

The steps are:

- Enable expermintal Razor:
  Option->Environment -> Preview Featurs-> Enable expermintal Razor
  editor (need restart)
- Put the cursor over @{code}  or press Control + .     //dot
- Dropdown menu is displayed with "Extract block to code behind"
- Click "Extract block to code behind"
- Then Vs2019 extract the code in a new *.razor.cs file being created side-by-side
  e.g "Counter.razor.cs" for the counter.razor Component.

The generated class sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab2.Pages
{
    public partial class Counter
    {
        private int currentCount = 0;

        private void IncrementCount()
        {
            currentCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The generated partial class **does not inherit from** `ComponentBase` and that will need to be resolved.