# Adding a razor page in Blazor Project creates a .cshtml file

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm following a tutorial trying to create a blazor project.

It says to add a razor page.  When I right click on Pages folder ->Add->Razor Page, I get this prompt.

[image: Prompt to create razor page]

No matter what options I pick, the new file is a .cshtml file, not a .razor file.

I see other .razor files in the same folder by default.

Target Framework: .NET Core 3.1

Am I missing something?

Comment: you should be adding a razor component, Pages folder ->Add->New item then pick razor component which has a purple icon on it.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.4.3.

Instead of creating a new "Blazor Page", go to the dialog to add a "New Item".  From ASP.NET Core, Select "Blazor Component".  This will create a new file called YourComponent.razor.

Bonus Fact: To create a code-behind file for the component, add a new class and specify the name YourComponent.razor.cs.  Declare the class partial (because the .razor file itself makes a partial class declaration).

I am also new to Blazor and this has been a source of confusion for me.  I hope that they make it more straight-forward in the next version of Visual Studio.

Comment: For visualization -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/66120934/4990642