# Blazor Server - 'Code Behind' pattern: OnInitializedAsync(): no suitable method found to override

Tags: code-behind, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor (Server) application which runs perfectly fine, and which adheres to all rules set by `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` and `StyleCop.Analyzers`.

A heavily cut-down razor page is as follows:

```
@inherits OwningComponentBase<MyService>
@inject IModalService ModalService
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

// UI code

@code
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ElementReference myElementReferenceName;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await this.myElementReferenceName.FocusAsync(this.JSRuntime);
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ....
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.TokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    protected void ShowModalEdit(object someObject)
    {
        .....
        Modal.Show<MyPage>("Edit", parameters);
    }
}
```

Note#1: I used `@inherits OwningComponentBase<MyService>` based on [Daniel Roth's suggestion](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10448)

Note#2: I am using the [Chris Sainty's Modal component](https://github.com/Blazored/Modal) component

However, when I try to move all the code from the `@code {...}` section to a"Code Behind" partial class ("MyPage.razor.cs"), then I run into the following errors....

> 'MyPage' does not contain a definition for 'Service' and no accessible
> extension method 'Service' accepting .....
>
> 'MyPage.OnAfterRenderAsync(bool)': no suitable method found to override
>
> 'MyPage.OnInitializedAsync()': no suitable method found to override
>
> The type 'MyPage' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic
> type or method 'IModalService.Show(string, ModalParameters,
> ModalOptions)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'MyPage' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase'.

Suggestions?

Comment: Show (the outline of) the CodeBehind class.

Comment: Partial classes are [only available in Core 3.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-core-3-1-preview-1/), what version are you on?

Comment: I'm using Core 3.1 latest preview

Comment: inherit from ComponentBase is enough in code behind

Comment: this is just crazy. It builds on my PC. It won't build on my mac. .net 6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `MyPage.razor.cs` should inherit from `ComponentBase` class and your `Mypage.razor` should inherit from `MyPage.razor.cs`.

In your "code-behind" class you should use `[Inject]` attribute for every service you are injecting and make them at least `protected` properties to be able to use them in your razor components.

Below is an example from one of my testing apps, please note this uses .net-core 3.0, in 3.1 you can use partial classes.

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"
@inherits IndexViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">

        @if (users == null)
        {
            <p><em>Hang on while we are getting data...</em></p>
        }
        else
        {
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-danger">Id</th>
                        <th class="text-danger">Username</th>
                        <th class="text-danger">Email</th>
                        <th class="text-danger">FirstName</th>
                        <th class="text-danger">LastName</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var user in users)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@user.Id</td>
                            <td>@user.Username</td>
                            <td>@user.Email</td>
                            <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                            <td>@user.LastName</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**IndexViewModel.cs**

```
public class IndexViewModel : ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    #region Private Members
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    [Inject]
    private IToastService ToastService { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Protected Members
    protected List<User> users;

    [Inject] IUsersService UsersService { get; set; }

    protected string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public IndexViewModel()
    {
        users = new List<User>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods


    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetUsers().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task GetUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            await foreach (var user in UsersService.GetAllUsers(cts.Token))
            {
                users.Add(user);
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage($"{ nameof(GetUsers) } was canceled at user's request.", "Canceled");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: Log the exception and filter the exception messages which are displayed to users.
            ShowErrorMessage(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ShowErrorMessage(string message, string heading ="")
    {
        //ErrorMessage = message;
        //StateHasChanged();
        ToastService.ShowError(message, heading);
    }

    private void ShowSuccessMessage(string message, string heading = "")
    {
        ToastService.ShowSuccess(message, heading);
    }

    protected void Cancel()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Support

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                cts.Dispose();
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Also, not sure about using .ConfigureAwait(false) on the UI thread in the method `OnInitializedAsync()`

Comment: As an aside: ...why is it these guys neglect something so important as the inheritance chain?

Comment: The reason mine was saying it couldn't find the methods, no method to override, etc. is because I had not corrected the namespace to be the same as the *.razor* view.

Comment: @IAbstract how are you suppose to know what namespace your razor view is, when you look at it there is no mention of any namespace?

Comment: @Paul: by default use the directory structure

Comment: This worked for me except for I did not need to add any inheritance to the `.razor` page. I only needed to have the `razor.cs` file inherit from `CompnentBase `. This may be because I am using `.NET 5` instead of the `.NET core 3.x` as in the question.

Answer (score 15):

#### TLDR

Make sure the namespace in your `razor.cs` file is correct

#### Longer explanation

In my case, I got this error when I put the class in the wrong namespace. The `page.razor.cs` file was in the same directory as the `page.razor` file and it contained a partial class [as accepted by the October 2019 update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59470941/8353218).

However, even though the files were located in `path/to/dir`, `page.razor.cs` had a namespace of `path.to.another.dir`, which led to this error being thrown. Simply changing the namespace to `path.to.dir` fixed this error for me!

Comment: This was the case for me. I use project names such as `OfficeReports.Api` and then name spaces like `OfficeReports.Api.Pages`.     Turns out this naming approach is incompatible with the way VS uses the Project Name + the folder structure to automatically create name spaces for the Razor pages. If I use `OfficeReportsApi` as my project name, resulting in `OfficeReportsApi.Pages`, the name spaces automatically resolve  as expected and having the C# class inherit from `ComponentBase` is unnecessary.

Comment: This has had me tearing what little hair I have left out. I created a `page.razor` and `page.razor.cs` file in a folder `folder1`. That got checked into source control, and all worked. Then the folder got renamed to `Folder1`, the name spaces adjusted accordingly automatically. However the rename didn't take in source control for some now unknown reason, so it remained `folder1`. It worked on my PC, but not on my colleagues as he had `folder1` but the namespace was `Folder1`.

Comment: Believe it or not, this was the solution for me. I moved few Razor components from one folder to another and it did not update the namespace automatically. I had to make the changes manually and the error went away. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this.  My components were all moved into a folder under the Pages folder and the namespace didn't change to match the new location.  It caused my code-behind to not be found by razor.

Comment: I renamed the folder, and it didn't update the namespace. This works

Answer (score 7):

I came across this error when I used partial class approach, and I was trying to scaffold Identity. I changed to base class approach it was resolved.

Partial class I was using after adding a component say `MyComponent`, I added a class to `MyComponent.razor.cs` for injecting services:

```
public BuildingServices Services { get; set; }
```

For base class approach after adding `MyComponent`, I added a class to `MyComponent.razor.cs` change the class name and make it inherit from `componentBase`:

```
MyComponentBase : ComponentBase
```

And I placed this at the top of `MyComponent.razor`:

```
@inherits MyComponentBase
```

Use protected keyword to make your methods accessible.

Comment: This would be a great comment for the accepted answer that *actually* explains *how* to do this.

Comment: Explicitly specifying the inheritance in the code behind file (view.razor.cs) from ComponentBase fixed it.  

I would like to point out that the problem was only an Intellisense issue as the program compiled and worked correctly.  

This behavior is different than WPF and the rest of c# for a partial class where it is optional to restate the inheritance.  In fact ReSharper gives a warning when adding  ": ComponentBase " as "already specified in other parts"

Answer (score 0):

All the above points are very true.  FWIW, and just to add a weird thing that I was finding with this issue; I could not get that error to go away.  Everything was declared as it should be.  Once you have ruled out all potential coding issues, I have found exiting VS, coming back in, and rebuilding clears it up.  It is almost like VS just will not let go of that error.

Answer (score 0):

It took two days of cleaning, rebuilding, ... and it turned out to be a cut and paste error. I copied the razor file from another, similar class, and left this at the top by mistake:

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<Person> localizer
```

'Person' was the wrong class, it wasn't defined by any of the include statements. For some strange reason the only error was "OnInitialized() No method found to override."

Answer (score 0):

I found this when upgrading to 6.0.  I had to switch from using base classes to using partial classes!

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me was dragging the .razor file into Shared folder and dragging it back to the original folder. As per spmoran-blazor's answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/7240#issuecomment-1372482716)

Answer (score 0):

It's the type of error that can have multiple cause. In my case it was so weird that I thought what I had changed recently and it was an install of more recent .Net 7 SDK.  I desinstalled it leaving the original .NET installed with VS 2022 and everything now compiles instead of 69 error of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

MyComponent.razor file:

```
<h1>@Message</h1>
```

MyComponent.razor.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace MyProject.Client.Shared;

public class MyComponent : ComponentBase
{
    string Message = "Hello";
}
```

somtime **visual studio** steel show error in Error List window. for making sure you have error or not **build** the blazor project.

Answer (score 0):

I have Blazor .net 7 VS 2022. I got same issues, I Created new folder and copied all files one by one into new folder(Here namespace is updated) and issues resolved. Thank you, Eugine.