# How to add a Partial Class to a component in Blazor in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm not finding where should I click to create a partial class in visual studio 2019.

After I create a new "Razor Component" file, I can't add the partial class to it.

Where do I add it?

Comment: you do it manually, just create class with the same name and .cs extension

Comment: Add `.razor.cs` class manually to the same folder, and make sure they both are in the same namespace (the `@namespace` directive in Razor component might be necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? : - razor page with "code-behind" class

[image]

Comment: if you use partial class in code behind class name should be the same as in component: Weather. And you don't need inherit in this case.

Answer (score 17):

There are two ways to add code behind to Razor component:

1. Add Base class and in component add `@inherits` this class, how is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553942/240564). In this case base class shouldn't be partial.
2. Since October 2019 [we can use partial classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59470941/240564).
   You can just add class name with the same name, adding .cs extension, mark it as partial class:

[image]

And you don't need to use `@inherits` in this case.

See [Partial class support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#partial-class-support) doc.

Comment: Is there any consideration, which method is better in which case?

Comment: @paburgos, I prefer second, I think it's more elegant

Comment: The second method is also more similar to what Microsoft has always done with GUI frameworks. Think about Windows Forms or WFP: The code-behind class is always a partial class, the same class as the UI one, it's never the base class.

Comment: @Alexan are there any technical limitations to one or the other option?

Comment: @metabuddy, I think that second method available starting with .NET Core 3.1

Comment: When i use partial class getting error Error CS0260 Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'CounterPartialClass'; another partial declaration of this type exists

Comment: The second option is great. However, make sure that the namespace of the `razor.cs` file is correct. Otherwise this won't work!

Comment: Note that the ": ComponentBase" is optional for the Partial Class Support option.

Answer (score 4):

Another way: (vs 2022)

Right click the @Code section, pick Quick Actions and Refactorings, select Extract block to code behind.

[image]