# Moving Blazor code to code-behind - simple example

Tags: blazor, code-behind

I just started going through the Blazor tutorial, and am trying to get a grasp on the code.  I have a razor page that looks like this (from the tutorial):

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<!--
    This has been moved to the code-behind.
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount() {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
-->
```

The code behind is giving me a couple of errors, saying Counter has already been defined and IncrementCount already exists.  My code behind looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorApp8.Pages {

    public partial class CounterCode : ComponentBase {

        protected int currentCount = 0;

        protected void IncrementCount () {
            currentCount++;
        }


    }

}
```

I know I have done something simple wrong, but not sure what.  Can someone assist?

Comment: Why do you need a partial class?

Comment: I don't.  That was me trying to figure out what I was doing.  I had just left out a line of code (see answer below).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556099/240564

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  In your client-side code, you must inherit from your class, like this:

```
@inherits CounterCode   <!-- This is what I missed -->
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Hi Brian, just a note to look into for later; The partial class approach can work well, but you might have some issues if you get into Generic Components and more complex scenarios. In those cases, set up a base class as the code behind (not partial), then inherit that base class in the razor file. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Good info.  Thanks, Nik!  This is new and exciting.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the other way to create a code behind file.

Create a new class file Counter.razor.cs within the same directory. Add partial to the class. Done!